# Why did Hashem want to save the garbage?

Tags: parashat-noach, mabul, parsha

The following question was posed to me by my 10-year-old sister. First I laughed, then it made me think. As far as I've researched, no meforshim discuss this topic.

Hashem commanded Noach to build the Teivah 3 stories high (Bereishis 6 16). Rashi (there, based on Sanhedrin 108b) explains that the top floor was for the humans, the middle floor for the animals, and the bottom for the waste.

What my sister and I are struggling with is why do we need an entire floor to save the waste? Why not just dump it outside? The world was one big trash can!

Comment: There's an answer here - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76892/22152

Comment: Wasn’t the ark sealed pretty tightly shut? Wouldn’t have been so easy to dump the garbage

Comment: @JoelK Well we know that Noach opened a "חלון" to release the raven and the pigeon. Anyways, my question is a lot more fundamental than just logistics. I'm wondering why we needed 3 floors to begin with.

Comment: @Dov My question is according to the Gemara and Rashi that maintain otherwise.

Comment: You could probably make a whole pro environment drasha from this

Comment: @CuriousYid don't forget that this waste we're discussing is, well, "all-natural."

Comment: Maybe they wanted to be eco-friendly.